# Ubuntu 22.04.1 server: Putty will not accept any keyboard input properly when Putty is displaying a GUI in command prompt

Tags: command-line, ssh, putty

**Background:**
While using Putty on Win10 to SSH into an Ubuntu 22.04.1 headless server, this problem happens.

**PROBLEM description**:
As seen in the image below, showing the Putty text interface, the arrow keys will just randomly type out giberish in the middle of the GUI and not cause the cursor in the GUI to move. The dialog box appeared after latest update (2022-09-24th), it appeared after `sudo apt dist-upgrade` had ran its course.

[image]

**More Info**:
I just tried to `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`, with the same setup above, and the resulting "dialog" GUI didn't have any the problem described above. I am able to navigate the dialog box with keyboard (arrow keys, tab key, enter key) without problem:
[image]

Comment: A must read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @David hi, I have updated the question. I suspect that it was a `apt upgrade` unique problem

Comment: @eliu Are you saying the problem is no longer reproducible now, but you aren't entirely sure what fixed it?  If so, we should probably close it out as such.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds problem is consistently reproducible. I just found a work around, that's all. Also, I believe this is a Putty problem instead of an Ubuntu problem. I probably should try Windows' cmd or powershell or linux's cli

Comment: I have a similar issue. The popup cannot be clicked and the CLI must be cleared to continue

Answer (score 1):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to send the `apt dist-upgrade` process to the background.
2. `fg` to bring the last process that you background-ed, which is the unfinished `apt dist-upgrade`, to the foreground.

Once completed, the CLI GUI interface will accept keyboards keys again.